# Gridview Paging not working after button click in asp web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have dropdowns and a button in a webpage. After this button click Im getting the griview with page numbers. But when I click on any page number the gridview is disappearing (Initially my panel is invisible).I have tried many solutions, but non of them working. can you check whts wrong in the code.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gv_AllEmployees" runat="server"
    class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    OnRowDataBound="gv_AllEmployees_RowDataBound"
    AllowPaging="true" PageSize="15"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gv_AllEmployees_PageIndexChanging">

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt_Departments = ViewsLogic.GetDepartments();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlDepartment.DataSource = dt_Departments;
        ddlDepartment.DataTextField = "DepartName";
        ddlDepartment.DataValueField = "DeptId";
        ddlDepartment.DataBind();
        ddlDepartment.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Department", "Select Department"));

        ListItem lst = new ListItem("All Departments", "-1");
        ddlDepartment.Items.Insert(ddlDepartment.Items.Count, lst);
       this.BindAllEmpLog();
        //gv_AllEmployees.Visible = true;
    }

}

protected void gv_AllEmployees_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gv_AllEmployees.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindAllEmpLog();

}

void BindAllEmpLog()
{

    dt_AllEmpLog = ViewsLogic.GetAllEmpLog(date.Date);
    //gv_AllEmployees.PageIndex = newPageIndex;
    gv_AllEmployees.DataSource = dt_AllEmpLog;

    gv_AllEmployees.DataBind();
    pnl_AllEmployees.Visible = true;
}

protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnl_Grids.Visible = false;
    lblError.Visible = false;
    pnl_AllEmployees.Visible = false;
    date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
    if (ddlDepartment.SelectedIndex < 1)
    {
        pnl_Grids.Visible = false;
        pnl_AllEmployees.Visible = false;
        lblError.Text = "Please Select a department from the list";
        lblError.Visible = true;

    }
   else if (ddlDepartment.SelectedIndex == ddlDepartment.Items.Count - 1) //If last item Selected
    {
        BindAllEmpLog();


    }
    else
    {
```

Comment: Please post the markup of the grid view as well

Comment: do you try debug? any error(s)? And while u select 2nd page(example) what is the value here (dt_AllEmpLog = ViewsLogic.GetAllEmpLog(date.Date);) ?

Comment: yes debugged at index2, it is going to this method (gv_AllEmployees_PageIndexChanging) and displaying the page with out grid. It is not going to this method (" void BindAllEmpLog())

Comment: what is a datatype of dt_AllEmpLog ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys. I found the solution. I was not getting the data in the datatable on the index change because of the following line. I copied this line in the BindAllEmpLog() method. then it is working fine.

```
date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
```